# getting text from dynamically added edit text in linear layout

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-linearlayout

I have added dynamically Linear Layout which have edit field, now i want get the text from those edit fields. Here is my code for adding layout dynamically

```
linearLayoutForm = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutForm);
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final LinearLayout newView = (LinearLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.single_skill_row, null);
                newView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                ImageButton btnRemove = (ImageButton) newView.findViewById(R.id.btnRemove);
                btnRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        linearLayoutForm.removeView(newView);
                    }
                });
                linearLayoutForm.addView(newView,0);
            }
        });
```

I have tried to get text with this code but i got null pointer exception.

```
register_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            LinearLayout et2=(LinearLayout) linearLayoutForm.getChildAt(linearLayoutForm.getChildCount());
            EditText e = (EditText) et2.getChildAt(et2.getChildCount());
            String s=e.getText().toString();
});
```

here is XML of single_skill_row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rowdetail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editDescricao"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.62"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1">
        <!--<requestFocus />-->
    </EditText>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnRemove"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/btn_remove"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_remove_black_18dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post your logcat please

Comment: Would you add you xml file single_skill_row.xml?

Comment: xml file has added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

First of All in your class you add a field:

```
...
EditText myEditText;
...
```

Then after adding your linearLayout you store your editText in the field like this:

```
...
final LinearLayout newView = (LinearLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.single_skill_row, null);
myEditText = newView.findViewById(R.id.editDescricao);
...
```

After that in the onClick callback of your button you can get it's text like this:

```
register_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        String text = myEditText.getText().toString();
});
```

Comment: From this I get text from the first edit field. i want to get text from all edit fields that has been added dynamically

Comment: You can get them all like this. Just add a field, store a reference when you inflate view, get the text in onClick callback from those reference

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with findViewById

```
register_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        LinearLayout et2=(LinearLayout) linearLayoutForm.getChildAt(linearLayoutForm.getChildCount());
        EditText e = (EditText) et2.findViewById(R.id.editDescricao);
        String s=e.getText().toString();
});
```

Comment: From this I get text from the first edit field. i want to get text from all edit fields that has been added dynamically.

Comment: it return null pointer exception on the second line of onClick method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply like this:

first create a special row layout in order to add it easily programmatically and then work that way:

```
    private LinearLayout parentLinearLayout;
    private List<View> rowViewList = new ArrayList<View>();


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_meeting);

        parentLinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.parent_linear_layout);

    }
```

/** here, you add onClick ="onAddField" on your button, directly in your layout
what happened in this method is that you inflate your LinearLayout, you add the special row layout you created earlier with the id, finally, you add this new View onto the rowViewList (the List) and you add this view to the LinearLayout you declared in the beginning*/

```
    public void onAddField(View v) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
        getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_row_you_want_to_add, null);
        rowViewList.add(rowView);
        parentLinearLayout.addView(rowView, parentLinearLayout.getChildCount());
    }
```

/** here, you add on the button in your layout onClick="getText"
create your View view, your Edittext and your String which will get all the text, and you will only have to go through the List you created earlier rowViewList*/

```
public void getText(View view) {
    View viewRow;
    EditText editText;
    String allEditText = "";
    for (int i = 0; i<rowViewList.size(); i++){
        viewRow = rowViewList.get(i);
        editText = viewRow.findViewById(R.id.mail_edit_text);
        allEditText = allEditText + ", " + editText.getText().toString();
    }
}
```

Hope that it helped you